# How to create new Kibana visualization through REST?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I want to automate the creation of a set visualizations for new kibana/elasticsearch installations.

So I need to know if I can automate this, independent the programming language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no APIs yet in Kibana to manage the searches, visualizations and dashboards. Some feature requests have been suggested ([here](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/3580) and [here](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/3456)) but they are still being discussed.

However, since Kibana visualizations are stored in the `.kibana` index with the `visualization` mapping type, you can definitely GET them, learn how they are built, modify them and PUT them again.

For a visualization named "Top consumers by country", you can get the visualization spec using

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/.kibana/visualization/Top-consumers-by-country
```

You'll get a document containing the `title` of your visualization, another field called `visState` containing the specification of your visualization (obvisouly different for each visualization) and finally a field named `kibanaSavedObjectMeta` which contains the Elasticsearch query and index details.

You can also view/edit/export the same data in [Settings > Objects > Visualizations](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/blob/de8d2e223ca3f474f5dad96c236d807145d2c030/docs/settings.asciidoc#managing-saved-searches-visualizations-and-dashboards)